# Yup validate one of several possible strings

Tags: yup

I have:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  title: yup.string().trim().required(),
  taste: yup.string().defined(), // <<< this needs to be different
);
```

However, the title makes sense because a title can be any string, but for taste, it needs to be either "Sweet", "Salty", or "Spicy".

How do you do this with yup?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with an `enum`, e.g.:

```js
enum Taste{
  Sweet = "Sweet",
  Spicy = "Spicy",
  Salty = "Salty",
}
```

Then use this enum in your schema:

```js
taste: Yup.mixed<Taste>().oneOf(Object.values(Taste)),
```

Comment: What if one of the possible strings is "", or the strings are "$$" and "$$$"?

Comment: You can add `DoubleDollarSign = "$$"` and so forth to the enum. That can get clunky at a certain point if there's a giant range of values you'd accept. Alternatively, you could use `Yup.string().test()` to perform whatever sort of validation you want in a function, e.g. `.test('len', 'Must be exactly 5 characters', val => val.length === 5)`.